# python - daemonize bottlepy script

Tags: python-3.x, daemon, bottle

I'm using a Bootle Python Web Framework to develop webapps on Ubuntu.
Is there any effective way to daemonize script that starts default bottlepy webserver?

Thank you.

**UPD:** Now I'm using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for this purposes.

Comment: Easiest ways: `python app.py &` - run in background. `nohup python app.py &` - run in background with ability to logout from console.

Comment: I recommend using uWSGI behind a simple Nginx...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reclosedev mentions, `nohup ... &` will work without fuss.

You can also use something like [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/) Which has more options than using `nohup`.

Personally I run the following while developing with autoreload switched on:

```
while true; do python app.py ; done
```

which restarts the server if I write something stupid. Other solutions will force you to restart your server for a syntax error.

Deployment happens behind apache or lighttpd.

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu I use following steps:

1. Remember to insert full path to templates into `bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH`
2. Make script executable (`chmod +x <script_name>`)
3. Make symlink to script w/o .py extension
4. Navigate to /etc/init.d and copy skeleton to `<script_symlink_name>`
5. Modify new init script

   - Change NAME to `<script_symlink_name>`
   - Change DAEMON to `<path_to_script_symlink>`
   - Change DAEMON_ARGS to ""
   - Change DESCRIPTION
   - Add "--background" switch to `start-stop-daemon` (line w/o "--test" switch) in `do_start()`
6. Make init script executabe
7. Test via "`service <script name> start`"
8. Set autostart: `update-rc.d <script-name> defaults`

Answer (score 0):

You can use supervisord or monit to start/stop and restart the app.